# Using JavaScriptSerializer to get a dictionary from whatever structure

Tags: c#, json, string, dictionary

I want to have a JSON string (generated by a whatever tool converting Javascript structs into JSON) parsed into a Dictionary of strings (just strings). The problem is that the JSON I get can contain more structures, thus the final dictionary might contain other dictionaries inside when it comes to some fields.

### An example string

Say I have the following JSON string:

```
string json = @"{
  "name":"kyosuke",
  "surname":"kasuga",
  "city":
    {
      "name":"tokyo",
      "ku-ward":"minato",
      "prefecture":"tokyo",
      "island":"honshu"
    }
}";
```

### Dictionary of dictionaries

I would like to get this in C#:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = Converter.GetData(json);

dictionary["name"] as string != null;
dictionary["surname"] as string != null;
var subdictioary = dictionary["city"] as Dictionary<string,string>;
subdictionary != null;

subdictionary["name"] as string != null;
subdictionary["ku-ward"] as string != null;
subdictionary["prefecture"] as string != null;
subdictionary["island"] as string != null;
```

How can I use `JavaScriptSerializer` to achieve this? Thank you

### A note on JSON.Net

I cannot use JSON.Net, I must rely on the .NET framework. :(

Comment: Have you looked at JSON.net, if you want to work with dynamic JSON data in c# using a dictionary type syntax then it has the `JObject` wich does exactly that.

Comment: I know about that, however I cannot use that library here. I can rely on the .NET only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: @dbc: It is sure related! I will close this if the solutions proposed there do not work

Answer (score 0):

This question has a proper answer here: [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object).

By following the approach described there, it is possible to achieve everything I need. Please note how this question poses a little more specific detailed scenario than the one reported in linked question.